# Using Layer-List and the colors of all items is being ignored when put on the button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a custom icon with a circle and a drawable image but drawable image is having its color set to white instead of the color that its tint is defined as

I have tried changing the style and multiple other things but the inner image of the circle always comes out white.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">

            <solid
                    android:color="#ffffff"/>

            <size
                    android:width="120dp"
                    android:height="120dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_fingerprint" android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

The button

```xml
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/toFingerprintReader"
            style="@style/Widget.Jackpot.Button"
            app:icon="@drawable/layer_list_fingerprint"
            android:layout_width="331dp"
            android:layout_height="312dp"
            app:iconSize="200dp" app:iconGravity="textStart"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="171dp"/>
```

The Style

```xml
  <style name="Widget.Jackpot.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/teFU8.jpg
Actual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MrFQ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `app:iconTint="@null"` to your button.

Like Below Code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/toFingerprintReader"
        style="@style/Widget.Jackpot.Button"
        app:icon="@drawable/layer_list_fingerprint"
        android:layout_width="331dp"
        android:layout_height="312dp"
        app:iconSize="200dp"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconTint="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

The output using this code:

[image]

I hope its work for you.